# How to create two way binding in angularjs using JSON?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Actually my requirement is want to create form controls like textbox, dropdown, date/time picker etc..

The above controls i want create using JSON , I will have all the Meta Data in the form of JSON. 
   Using that JSON i can able to create the controls using Angular Directive, Now i want to modify the any of the controls in the VIEW
   I need to change the Control as well as the JSON. Here i need to use two way binding.

Please anyone help me to achieve this or Provide any examples likewise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but if you're just needing to convert an object literal on your scope to JSON, angular.toJson should fit your needs.

```
$scope.object = {
    foo: 'bar'
}

var result = angular.toJson($scope.object);
```

Bind $scope.object to your control using ng-model and use angular.toJson in your controller to convert the scope object to JSON to use elsewhere as needed.